# Hibernate type mapping short vs byte / JPL interface vs native query

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

im trying to select dynamically generated number of columns from an MSSql table with java and hibernate.

**Problem:**

Hibernate returns different return type depending on which query method I use for MSSql TinyInt values.

**Info**:

HibernateVersion:5.4.12.Final

HibernateDialect: `dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect`

Simplified Entity:

```
    CREATE TABLE SampleEntity
(
    [ID] [int], -- PK etc...,
    [SomeTinyInt] [tinyint]
)
```

Hibernate generated entity class:

```
@Entity
public class SampleEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "SomeTinyInt")
    private Short someTinyInt;

//set get...
}
```

Now selecting the entity via `JPQL` works fine.

`SELECT e FROM SampleEntity`

Selecting the Entity via dynamically generated query string and executed as `Native Query`
e.g.

`SELECT SomeTinyInt FROM SampleEntity`

Returns an array with the columns as expected but `SomeTinyInt` is returned as `byte` and not as `short`.

**Question:**
Is there a way to unify the return type?

Comment: I guess the returned type of native query will depend of hibernate dialect what you use. What hibernate dialect do you use? What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Hi, i added the dialect and hibernate version to the question. Thanks for pointing out missing info

Comment: Ah, no i get it. so the dialect explains why it behaved differently for the h2 in memory database. That just leaves the question why it behaves differently for the mssql dialect with the different query types